# Why won't Comment Notify replace the unsubscribe token in notification emails?

Tags: tokens

In short: when the Comment Notify module (under Drupal 7) sends a notification email to anyone subscribed to comments on an article on my site, it refuses to replace the token for the unsubscribe URL. Instead, it just appears in the email as `[comment-subscribed:unsubscribe-url]`.

This is a [known bug](https://drupal.org/node/952072) for previous versions of Comment Notify, but I upgraded it weeks ago (and was sure to run `update.php`. I'm now running v7.x-1.2 (I've also tried the dev version). Drupal itself is not at the latest version, but unless I know it's a bug in core, I really don't want to go through the pain of upgrading just yet.

I have cleared the cache, run cron and truncated the `cache_form` table. I have checked that the `variable` table entry for Comment Notify uses the correct token. And yet, it still refuses to perform the token replacement for that token alone.

The template for the one of the Comment Notify emails is simply:

```
There's a new comment on "[comment:node:title]":

Author: [comment:author]

[comment:body]

--
You can view the comment at [comment:url]
Stop receiving notifications for this post at [comment-subscribed:unsubscribe-url]

[site:name]
[site:url]
```

What else can I try to get this working, or to debug the problem further?

Comment: I just started using Comment Notify. The problem appears to have been corrected. I'm not seeing any token issues.